# Freebase rdf changed format?

Tags: freebase

I've been using the freebase rdf dump and in the latest dump (Jan 26, 2014) I noticed that the file size is smaller and the property looks a lot different. For example, the schema for University of Ottawa (https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/rdf/m/011kn2) doesn't have the property 'ns:location.location.geolocation..location.geocode.latitude' that the old dump used to have. Has Google changed the API or is this a one-time glitch? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the property name has two adjacent periods (..) makes it look buggy to me.  Perhaps they just fixed the bug.  If so, hopefully it's a permanent improvement not a "glitch."